# jQuery datatable pagination not working with mvc view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm working on an MVC application. The table data is returned as a view from the controller. After binding the rows in the razor view, I'm initializing the datatable. The no. of rows returned is 50.
The issue is, the datatable displays all the 50 records and hence there is no pagination. I would like it to show only 10 records per page and then paginate.

Also, I do not want to get the data page by page. The total count, which is 50 in this case, is decided by the end user. That's the main reason, I choose datatables as it provides sorting, search & pagination with no coding.

So, does the pagination feature work if the data is bound to DOM and then initialized. If not, what is the best way to do it.
Here is the code:

```
@model ResultOutput
<table class="tblKeyMetrics" role="grid">
        <thead>
            <tr role="row">
                <th class="">Value</th>                
                <th class="">Impressions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        @if (Model.KeyMetrics != null && Model.KeyMetrics.Count > 0)
        {
          <tbody>
            for (int index = 0; index < Model.KeyMetrics.Count; index++)
            {
                KeyMetrics metric = Model.KeyMetrics[index];

                    <tr role="row">
                        <td>@metric.value</td>                        
                        <td>@metric.impressions</td>
                    </tr>                                        
            }
          </tbody>
        }
        else
        {
            <tbody>
                <tr class="row">
                    <td colspan="3">
                    No results found.
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        }
    </table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
        InitializeDataTable($(".tblKeyMetrics"));
    });

function InitializeDataTable(tbl) {
    if (!$.fn.DataTable.isDataTable($(tbl))) {
        $(tbl).DataTable({
            pageLength: 10,
            iDisplayLength: 10,                
            "paging": true
        });
    }    
}
</script>
```

using jquery.dataTables.min.js v1.10.16 with dataTables.bootstrap.min v3

Comment: try putting your initialize function before the document.ready

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Do you want me to change the order or trigger the function before document.ready. Please explain.

Comment: order put function first then your initializtion in document ready

Comment: you are already passing $(".tblKeyMetrics") to your InitializeDataTable funciton. So in your function you need not use $ again, you can just write isDataTable(tbl) and tbl.DataTable. Please let me know if that works.

Comment: @PriyankPanchal. It's all the same. Did not work.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad. No luck with that.

Comment: change: `InitializeDataTable($(".tblKeyMetrics"));` to : `InitializeDataTable(".tblKeyMetrics");`

Comment: @EhsanSajjad No change. The issue is not with the $. The datatable gets initialized either way. The issue is with pagination. All the 50 rows are displayed. Whereas I want only 10 to be displayed in first page and then the pagination to work. I'm suspecting, will this work only if ajax call is made inside the DataTable({}) function?

Comment: Is the datatables plugin definitely being applied?  eg are you getting the row sorting functionality?  That would at least prove that the table is being intialised.  Another thing to consider is the version of datatables you're using - I'm guessing it's v1.10, but you've used `iDisplayLength` which is v1.9 syntax.  Shouldn't cause a problem but just something I noticed.

Comment: @markpsmith. The datatable are definetely initialized. The sort, search works fine. I'm using v1.10.16 along with dataTables.bootstrap.min v3

Comment: the `"paging": true` is not needed, just `pageLength` needs to be provided

Comment: This should definitely work.  I have created a very simple example on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/markps/mu8tvo7k/1/).  You can see that without any additional initialisation, the paging works using `pageLength`.  Is there something else going on that we casn't see?

Comment: @markpsmith. The only diff. I see is in my case, the data is bound to DB in razor view.

Comment: There's not really any difference - you're still creating and populating the table in the dom before applying the plugin

Comment: In my case; I had recordsfiltered and recordsTotal switched around.